# Does anti-gravitating antimatter break any physical principles?

Tags: gravity, mass, antimatter

Other than experimental facts that antimatter gravitates the same as matter does, is there theoretically a reason why antiparticles can't create repulsive gravity?

Comment: This is a very complicated question, but overall there are no deep principle preventing anti-matter to anti gravitate and people are testing this hypothesis experimentally. For a basic introduction you can look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALmS9E87LCg

Comment: More on [gravity of antimatter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity+antimatter).

Answer (score 1):

General relativity (our best current theory of gravity) very much predicts that antimatter and matter behave the same gravitationally. In GR spacetime is curved by the presence of energy (more precisely by the stress energy tensor); it doesn't matter whether that energy is in the form of matter or antimatter. Similarly, objects move along geodesics in spacetime, whether those objects are made of matter or antimatter. So the recent experimental results confirm what most physicists expected. Of course such confirmation is still useful, because an unexpected result, however unlikely, would have told us something *very* interesting!